# Foundation Topbar Navigation - Do I use Toggler?

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I want to be able to click links in my top bar to display different content. Do I need to explicitly use data-toggler on each  tag in my top bar?This seems crazy. Is there an easier way to achieve the navigation I am looking for? Similar to the switcher for uikit? Thanks in advance as I am very new to the foundation.

Comment: I am not worried about the dropdown.  When "Profile" or "Settings" are clicked in my top bar I would like my browser to display the corresponding profile or settings page html under the top bar. I know I could add an onclick or similar jQuery trigger to the  links but I am wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the dropdown menus in the wrappers that will be toggling their opacity/visibility so that when you `:hover` over the element, the menu will appear below it or wherever you want for it to as a matter of fact.
[Here's the pen](https://codepen.io/justinrowe04/pen/PyxxQN).

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of Switcher reminds me of the tabs element of Foundation ([Tabs | Foundation for Sites 6 Docs](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/tabs.html)). Unlike the dropdown, the Tabs element remains visible after you click it, even if the mouse pointer moves out.